# If a collar of aluminium is on a slightly tapered shaft will heating the pulley near the centre cause the i/dia to expand and release the collar?

Tags: friction

I need to remove an aluminium collar that is attached by age or rust to a tapered steel shaft. I need to know if heating the collar or shaft will cause the expansion to allow the collar to move. I have tried hitting the collar parallel to it in a downward motion. I cannot add more as the question I have asked is self explanatory.
And you do not provide enough space to ask or explain more.

Comment: Depending on the application you're looking at, this might be a better question for [mechanics.SE] or [diy.se].

Answer (score 1):

The coefficient of thermal expansion for aluminum is greater than the coefficient of thermal expansion for steel, so heating the shaft should work.  For more info, see [this](https://amesweb.info/Materials/Linear-Thermal-Expansion-Coefficient-Metals.aspx) and [this](https://www.vedantu.com/physics/coefficient-of-linear-expansion).